# Method Overloading or method overriding?

Tags: c#, oop

In my C# application i have a base class, which contains a function Myfunction. 
I have a derived class from the above base class which also contains the same function as in base class, is this concept is correct implementation?

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public void MyFunction()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("");
   }
}


public class DerivedClass:BaseClass
{
    public void MyFunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

i am a newbee in Programing , sorry for my english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've actually [hidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) `BaseClass.MyFunction` by doing it that way.

If you want to override properly, you must declare the base version as `virtual` (or `abstract`) and then specify `override`:

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public virtual void MyFunction() { }
}

public class DerivedClass:BaseClass
{
    public override void MyFunction() { }
}
```

Overloading and overriding are different things. The above shows overriding. Overloading refers to when there are multiple methods with the same name, but different parameters. E.g. if you have these methods:

```
public void MyFunction(int i) {}
public void MyFunction(decimal d) {}
```

You would say that there are two *overloads* of MyFunction.

Comment: "You've actually hidden BaseClass.MyFunction by doing it that way. " -- No, not without a `new` keyword ... the OP's code won't compile.

Comment: @JimBalter It compiles with a warning, unless you add `new`.

Comment: My mistake. It *should* be an error; that it isn't is probably for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @JimBalter no problem. My link above actually explains why it's a warning: "Hiding an inherited name is specifically not an error, since that would preclude separate evolution of base classes. For example, the above situation might have come about because a later version of Base introduced an F method that wasn't present in an earlier version of the class. Had the above situation been an error, then any change made to a base class in a separately versioned class library could potentially cause derived classes to become invalid."

Answer (score 2):

No, this is wrong implementation for `method overloading`.

If you create a method with **same name**, and **same parameters** then it will be `method overriding`.

If you create a method with **same name**, but **different parameters** then it will be `method overloading`.

If you need to implement your example for `method overriding`, then add a `override` keyword on your `derived class method` and add a `virtual` keyword with your `base class method`:

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public virtual void MyFunction()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("");
   }
}


public class DerivedClass:BaseClass
{
    public override void MyFunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

If you want to implement an example of `overloading`, then you will just have to change the parameters of your both methods. Change means they must be different from each other. e.g. :

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
       public void MyFunction()
       {
          Console.WriteLine("");
       }
    }


    public class DerivedClass:BaseClass
    {
        public void MyFunction(string input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: "override class" -- no, it goes on the method. Also, your discussion of overloading is a bit off; overloaded methods are usually in the same class; having overloads in different classes is a code smell.

Comment: @JimBalter typing mistake.. and you are right they are usually in the same class. But here i was modifying his given example, so he could better understand

Comment: For better understanding, change the last one to `Console.WriteLine(input)` (actually, I would put that one in the base class, and have `MyFunction() { MyFunction(""); }` in the derived class).

Answer (score 0):

In this example, MyFunction in DerivedClass overrides MyFunction in BaseClass.

If you had another MyFunction, this time 'MyFunction(int parameter)', you would have overloaded MyFunction.

Comment: "In this example, MyFunction in DerivedClass overrides MyFunction in BaseClass." -- No it doesn't, it's an error. C# requires either a `new` keyword in the derived class or `virtual` in the base class and `override` in the derived class.

Comment: Oops, my mistake, it's only a warning. But in any sane shop such warnings aren't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You must overload/overrieds methods in this way

```
   public   class derived_Class : mybaseclass 
    {

        public override void mymethod()
        {
            // IF you want to call the base class function as well then you call base.mymethod() ; 
            base.mymethod();
        } 


    }

    class mybaseclass
    {

        // When you want to overide a method , you must use Virtual keyword
        public virtual void mymethod()
        {

        }

        // This is an overload of overload_method 
        // when you write many methods from same name with different arguments, it's an overload of the method
        public void overload_method()
        {
        } 
        public  void overload_method(string m)
        {

        } 

        // When you use an overload 
        public void use()
        {
            overload_method();
            overload_method(null); 
        } 
    }
```